# Writing rows from file geodatabase Table to NonGDB Table in SQL Server using Python

Tags: arcpy, sql, pyodbc

I have data in a file geodatabase table that I want to write into an existing table in SQL Server (not enterprise-enabled) using Python.  I am already using pyodbc to read SQL data elsewhere, but am open to using a different module to write this data.

How do I do this?

Comment: By "in SQL" do you mean "in Microsoft SQL Server"?  How are you using pyodbc to read a file geodatabase? If there's no geometry in the table, and you don't want to use arcpy, this is probably more appropriate in [so] or [dba.se] ("How to insert rows using pyodbc?")

Comment: Specifically I do mean Microsoft SQL Server, but examples from other RDBMS could probably get me close as well.  There is geometry but I am not writing it back.  I plan to use Arcpy as far as it will take me.  Particularly, should i just read from FGDB and insert to SQL row by row, or should I convert the entire table to an array or pandas data frame then insert all of that?

Comment: You can copy TableToTable in a dozen lines of code, if the database is geodatabase enabled. Formatting SQL statements could be accomplished in less that two score lines with an ArcSDESQLExecute cursor. There are so many alternatives that this is nearly *too broad* / *opinion-based*.

Comment: @Rex Please update the question with the specifics from your comment, and, when you post questions *[please include what you've actually tried yourself with verifyable source code](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3353/150)*.

Comment: This question might in fact be too broad.  Can it be deleted/closed out?

Comment: @Rex You have two options: 1) edit the question to improve it or 2) delete the question.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have a connection to the SQL Server database already you should be able to make a connection pretty easily. You can then use the [Copy Rows](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-rows.htm) tool which will do the work for you, e.g.

```python
input_data = '/path/to/data.gdb/featureclass'
output_data = '/path/to/connection.sde/tablename'

arcpy.CopyRows_management(input_data, output_data)
```

According to the docs any non-geometry column will be copied.

If you need to subset the original table columns, you can also create a [table view](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-table-view.htm) first and use that instead of the original table.